# Filtering a Pandas Dataframe by frequency

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have got a dataset with roughly 50k rows and 15 columns.
I need to pick only certain rows which follow the rule: 'if the string in column "C" appears more than 20 times in the dataset (within that column), pick that row'. It is basically filtering out based on the mode of a certain column.

At the end, I am expecting to have a dataset with around 5k rows (and 15 columns).

I tried to perform this by using value_counts() for the column but then I am unable to match the rest of the information to the specific row.

Thank you so much in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `groupby().transform` and boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('C')['C'].transform('size') >= 20]
```